# Specify multiple GRES type options in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I've been using SLURM to request specific GPUs, like so;

`--gres=gpu:TYPE:1`

On the cluster I'm using there are 4 different GPUs available, all with their specific gres types.

For some jobs I don't care which GPU is used, so I can specify:

`--gres=gpu:1`

However, sometimes I'd like to have some specific types, but among those dont really care about which one. Basically the first one that is available.

So I would hope to specify something like:

`--gres=gpu:TYPE1:1 OR --gres=gpu:TYPE2:1`

So that it would pick whichever is available first.

However, I've been unable to find such an option. This does option exist SLURM?

Answer (score 2):

Contrarily to the `--constraint` option, the `--gres` option does not allow logical constructs. One option would be to submit two jobs and `scancel` the one that starts later.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Our cluster is quite inhomogeneous, and I really wish there is a way to normalize the `gres` string.